# Long essay / short booklet (~10,000 words?) memoir of a husband caring for his wife dying from cancer

Tags: identification-request

I volunteer in end-of-life care among the materially disadvantaged in India. About 2 years ago, I had come across a long essay / short booklet (~10,000 words?) written by a person who was caring for his wife dying from cancer. As far as I remember, the wife hadn't died at the time of his writing.

The essay had struck me so deeply and profoundly, that I cried even on recalling it, not only while reading it over and over again. Because of this, I could never imagine that someday I may forget the title/author. But we almost always underestimate the fickle, transitory, volatile nature of human memory.

I remembered it today because I need it more than ever, and have been desperately searching for it for the past many weeks. Please do help if the experts here recall it from the following description:

1. One of the first points of the essay was how caring for a dying person is fundamentally different from care-giving when there is hope of recovery, even if the illness is a long, painful one.
2. Another powerful point was how almost each one of us would face an end-of-life care-giving situation, either for ourselves, or our loved ones.
3. The crucial role of early therapy: The author said that they went for therapy only after straining their relationship. But he strongly recommended that dying people and their care-givers should access therapy right from the beginning. Because relationship strain is inevitable. And pre-emptive intervention can avoid it.
4. Role of support groups: The author reported valuable emotional catharsis from venting out, even shouting in support group meetings.
5. This was the idea that shook my soul: That it is common and ok to feel angry, resentful, and even want early death of the dying person. That the stresses of terminal care often break down the care-giver no less than the dying person. And that this happens due to their deep love and devotion, not despite it. This is because lack of love would manifest as walking away, not caring everyday and pushing themselves to such limits that they completely break down.

Comment: This is going to be tough, because I imagine quite a few essays come out like this. Many won't have all the criteria, but it'll make sifting through the wrong ones that much more difficult.

Comment: @cmw Thank you for your comment. Should I remove some of the points to make it more specific? But even other similar essays would be quite valuable for my mental strength.

Comment: Oh, no, I wasn't suggesting changing anything. Just remarkingon how difficult it might be to track down this precise one. You're fine.

Comment: Can you provide some further information? Was the booklet in English? Was the writer Indian? You say you read it a couple years ago, but do you have any knowledge of when the essay was published? What did the physical book look like? Cover, size, print quality, etc.